# Navigation controller creates 2 views instead of 1

Tags: iphone, segue, navigationcontroller

I explain the situation : 
I've got a NavigationController + TableViewController and when I click on a cell, I've done a performSegueWithIdentifier to go to another View. I've done this through storyboard.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToCamera" sender:self];
```

In this view, I need to push a view which contain the camera overlay.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

This works fine but my problem is that the navigation controller seems to create 2 views and when I want to go back to the TableViewController, I need to click 2 times, the first time the button's name is "**Back**" and the second time the button's name is "**myTableView**"

I noticed that when I set the attribut animated to 'YES', I got this error message :

```
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
```

This problem seems to appear when there are 2 segue push in the same time but it isn't in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Executing:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

is indeed like performing a push segue, with the only difference that you are directly manipulating the stack of the navigation controller! What is your expected behavior?

I think what you want to do is directly performing the segue to the view controller with the camera overlay, am i wrong?